# "DLL missing" visual studio 2012?

Tags: dll, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, regsvr32

When i am starting visual studio 2012 `atl110.DLL` missing problem shows.
I download `atl110.Dll` from internet and i run command `regsvr32.exe atl110.dll`

The module "atl110.dll" may not compatible with the version of Winbdows that you'r running. Check if the module is compatible with an `x86 (32-bit)` or `x64 (64-bit)` version of regsvr32.exe. error message is shown my operating system is windows 8. 
how can i fix this problem.

Comment: > which is operating system using you? if you are using 64 bit os then
> you need to install 64 bit dll or if you are using 32 bit os then you
> need to install 32 bit dll.

Comment: i am using 32 bit operating system. but i am goggling for atl110.dll but i can't found appropriate dll.

Comment: I am also having this issue

Comment: @ChristianStewart lastly i re-install Visual studio :( for solve this 
i was tried many time to download dll but i can't found so better re-install visual studio

Comment: Same for me. Post this as an answer.

Comment: @ChristianStewart i think this is not a solution. when this dll was missed any idea? means what did yo do? then missing problem was happenend, in my case i don't know if problem root is found then better solution is also be invented.

Answer (score 2):

download

http://www.dll-files.com/dllindex/dll-files.shtml?atl110

and copy to `windows/system32`